# Are the forces between liquid molecules attractive or repulsive?

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension, molecules

Surface tension is explained by there being attractive forces between molecules as show in the diagram.[image]

But shoudn't repelling or pushing forces exist for there to be hydrostatic pressure.
How is this explained or am I wrong to assume so. Please comment if you think the question is inadequate, i will edit it.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatics#Hydrostatic_pressure "For a barotropic fluid in a conservative force field like a gravitational force field, the pressure exerted by a fluid at equilibrium becomes a function of force exerted by gravity. "

Comment: As it is stated, your question is not very clear to me. Is it about molecular forces, pressure, or surface tension? The  force between molecules is usually attractive when they are far apart and repulsive at shorter distances (see for example, the Lennard-Jones potential).

Comment: I dont understand how surface tension is explained by saying that molecules pull each other whereas molecules push each other (as in hydrostatic pressure)

Answer (score 1):

The intermolecular forces are both attractive and repulsive. For any material there is an energetically favorable mean interparticle distance, and particles that get too close by random thermal motion are repulsed and particles that drift too far are attracted, to a point. You can think of it as very similar to the force exerted by a spring, it is both attractive and repuslive.

Answer (score 1):

The liquid would not hold together if the forces between the molecules were always repulsive, so that should answer your overall question. That said, the forces would become repulsive if the distance between two molecules became less than a certain threshold, which is what prevents the liquid from collapsing in on itself.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure in general, in matter, is caused by the motion (usually thermal) of atoms and molecules, not directly by the forces between them.  For example, the kinematic model of an ideal gas uses point particles with no interactions, and the pressure of the gas is due to elastic collisions between the particles and the walls of the chamber.  This model relates temperature to pressure since the higher the temperature the higher the average kinetic energy of the particles and hence the greater the momentum change from particle-wall collisions which is directly the pressure.

It's more complicated in a liquid of course, and one models the motion of the particles using attractive and repulsive forces, but again the pressure to first approximation is due to collisions of the particles with the surface of interest.  Yes absolutely there are attractive and repulsive forces in a liquid, and these are critical to explaining the motion of the particles, but it is mainly the collision of particles that leads to pressure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So pressure is mainly due to intermolecular collisions. But are the forces between liquid molecules attractive or repulsive?

Comment: Both -others have now given answers to that effect that I completely agree with.  If you take the example of water, each molecule has a static electric dipole moment which contributes to attractive force between molecules.  However when the molecules get very close the repulsion of the electrons becomes the dominant force and this is repulsive.  So both.